# How do I send a post request using the Request library and Bluebird?

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, promise, bluebird

So heres my setup:

```
var Promise = require("bluebird");
var request = Promise.promisify(require('request'));
```

This works:

```
request('url')
```

It returns a promise

This doesn't:

```
request.post('url', {form: {type: 'artist'}})
```

gives me this error:

```
TypeError: Object function promisified(_arg0,_arg1) { ... }has no method 'post'
at /Users/beamer30/projects/wevo/controllers/music.js:85:30
at Array.map (native)
at MusicSearch.spotifyRelated (/Users/beamer30/projects/wevo/controllers/music.js:84:22)
at MusicSearch.findRelatedArtists (/Users/beamer30/projects/wevo/controllers/music.js:48:7)
at musicController.search (/Users/beamer30/projects/wevo/controllers/music.js:100:17)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/beamer30/projects/wevo/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:76:5)
at next (/Users/beamer30/projects/wevo/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:100:13)
at Route.dispatch (/Users/beamer30/projects/wevo/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:81:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/beamer30/projects/wevo/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:76:5)
at /Users/beamer30/projects/wevo/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:227:24
```

any ideas on how to make this work?
What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you promisify the request return you promisify only the returned function. Instead - use `promisifyAll` which promisifies a whole object. Since `request` is both you didn't get an error.

```
var Promise = require("bluebird");

var request = Promise.promisifyAll(require('request')); // this will work
```

Comment: Thanks unfortunately the post request is no longer sending correctly?
is there some .postAsync() function?

Comment: @gbachik yes exactly, you have to use `postAsync`

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum how do you get the body? promises then only accepts the 2nd argument of the callback as the body is the 3rd one.

Comment: @majidarif good question, By default bluebird (until v3) will resolve to an array and you can use spread: `request.getAsync("fooBar").spread(function(resp, body` and access it there or instead do `.get(1)` to get the second argument and then `then` it

Comment: Where is the documentation for postAsync?

Comment: Please read the bluebird promisifyAll docs - it's .post promisifie a